# Bypass pre-receive hook if branch already exist (pushed)

Tags: bash, github, git-bash

I have a pre-receive hook to check the naming convention for running Git project:

```html
valid_branch_regex="^(master|release-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}|[A-Z|0-9]{3,6}-[0-9]+-.*)"

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    echo "$refname : $oldrev ~ $newrev"
    current_branch=$refname
    short_current_branch="$(echo $current_branch | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"
done

message="There is something wrong with your branch name. Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract:\
 $valid_branch_regex. Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."

if [[ ! $short_current_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

The problem is that I want to bypass the branches which have been pushed before the script has been applied. Any idea to improve my current logic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to this question:

```html
valid_branch_regex="^(master|release-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}|[A-Z|0-9]{3,6}-[0-9]+-.*)"

zero_commit="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
message="There is something wrong with your branch name. Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract: \
$valid_branch_regex. Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    echo "$refname : $oldrev ~ $newrev"
    current_branch=$refname
    short_current_branch="$(echo $current_branch | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"
done

message="There is something wrong with your branch name. Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract:\
 $valid_branch_regex. Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."
    # Check for new branch or tag
    if [ "$oldrev" == "$zero_commit" ]; then
        short_current_branch="$(echo $current_branch | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"
    else
        echo "This is an existing branch, wont check the naming convention. \
Please be aware that the branch name should follow this contract: $valid_branch_regex"
        exit 0
    fi

if [[ ! $short_current_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0 
    if [[ ! $short_current_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
    then
        echo "$message"
        exit 1
    fi

done
exit 0
```